Angular + OidcSecurityService package + Forcing Signup
calling this.oidcSecurityService.authorize(); invokes the LOGIN page in cognito.
But my cognito setup also allows for sign-up, showing the "sign up" option below. Once clicked, it changes the form to "sign up".
Is there anything in the oidcSecurityService package that allows a redirect to sign up directly? Trying to save my users the need to click "sign up" to switch the cognito form to sign up.
I could not find such an option.

It doesn't look like it. Here's the source code: OidcSecurityService.authorize()

I think this is a question about the role of an external identity provider. You're not supposed to care if the user already has an account or not; you just redirect them to the provider and let the provider handle it all. If you want to shortcut them to a specific part of the external sign up/login process, you'll necessarily have to start caring about their enrollment state which is counter to the reason we use external auth providers to begin with.

More clearly, how do you plan to know when the user needs to sign up in order to directly link to the sign up form? That would require you to know who the current user is which would imply you can determine a user's identity before they're authenticated...

@DM at the point of wanting "sign up" I already know this is a new user as the onboarding flow begins on my web app, then redirected to cognito to do the actual account signup.
